# Power calculations for Wilcoxon test

Tags: r, simulation, statistical-power, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am running a Wilcoxon test to compare means between two groups (control and experiment) of unequal sample sizes. The distribution is right skewed and bound by zero for both groups.

I would like to run a power test for the Wilcoxon test. In this [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html) they describe a power test for a t test, which I used at first because I am also comparing two means:

```
> pwr.t2n.test(n1 = 125, n2=189, d = 0.3, sig.level = 0.05)

 t test power calculation 

         n1 = 125
         n2 = 189
          d = 0.3
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.7370368
alternative = two.sided
```

However, I have now found on this [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MKpower/vignettes/MKpower.html#power-and-type-i-error-simulations) a function allowing a simulation of power of a Wilcoxon test.

```
  ## functions to simulate the data
  ## group 1 - experimental
 rx <- function(n) rgamma(n, scale = 0.5, shape = 0.1)
 rx.H0 <- rx

 ## group 2 - control
 ry <- function(n) rgamma(n, scale = 1.5, shape = 0.1)
 ry.H0 <- function(n) rgamma(n, scale = 1.5, shape = 0.1)

 res.w <- sim.power.wilcox.test(nx = 189, rx = rx, rx.H0 = rx.H0,
                             ny = 125, ry = ry, ry.H0 = ry.H0)

Simulation Set-up
           nx = 189
           rx = function (n) , rgamma(n, scale = 0.5, shape = 0.1)
        rx.H0 = function (n) , rgamma(n, scale = 0.5, shape = 0.1)
           ny = 125
           ry = function (n) , rgamma(n, scale = 1.5, shape = 0.1)
        ry.H0 = function (n) , rgamma(n, scale = 1.5, shape = 0.1)
    sig.level = 0.05
           mu = 0
  alternative = two.sided
         iter = 10000
     conf.int = FALSE
  approximate = FALSE
         ties = FALSE

  Exact Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
     emp.power = 0.3096
emp.type.I.error = 0.3079

  Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
     emp.power = 0.3092
emp.type.I.error = 0.3072
```

I do not understand this function entirely, I am not sure whether nx and ny should correspond to the value of my sample size and I do not understand why we do not enter the effect size here. Can anybody clarify this?

Is this last option the only way to calculate power of a Wilcoxon test or is the first option also correct?